# Какой элемент видит метод has для WeakSet?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
let messages = [
  { text: "Hello", from: "John" },
  { text: "How goes?", from: "John1" },
  { text: "See you soon", from: "Alice" }
];

let answer = new WeakSet();

answer.add(messages[0]);
answer.add(messages[1]);
answer.add(messages[2]);

messages.shift()

alert("0: " + answer.has(messages[0]));
alert("1: " + answer.has(messages[1]));
alert("2: " + answer.has(messages[2]));
```

Метод shift() удаляет первый элемент массива, в нашем случае этот `{ text: "Hello", from: "John" }`
На экран выводится:

```
0: true
1: true
2: false
```

Почему `0: true`?

Если вместо метода shift() использовать delete messages[0], то вывод будет правильным:

```
0: false
1: true
2: true
```

Если вместо метода shift() использовать метод splice(0, 1), то вывод будет таким:

```
0: true
1: true
2: false
```

То есть тоже не правильным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод правильный.

Так работают методы [`.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) и [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Элемент массива удаляется, остальные сдвигаются.

То есть, после вызова

```
messages.shift()
```

или

```
messages.splice(0, 1)
```

В `messages` останутся следующие элементы:

```
[
  { text: "How goes?", from: "John1" },
  { text: "See you soon", from: "Alice" }
];
```

Таким образом ты на самом деле проверяешь наличие первого и второго элемента и под индексом 2 лежит `undefined` - так как элемента с таким индексом в массиве уже нет.